# Impossible to access input from within R Shiny UI module?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have the choices in a `radioButtons` input depend on the selection of a prior input, and I would like to wrap both inputs up in a UI module. I know that passing the inputs of one module to another requires passing to the server first. But I can't seem to access an input within the *same* UI.

Here's what I have in a single `app.r` (things will eventually get repeated over several tabs, thus the desire for a module, but we're keeping it simple for now):

```
library(shiny)

# Sidebar selector UI module
sidebarSel_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    # conditional choices for secondInput based on firstInput
    input2Choices <- if (ns(input$firstInput == 1)) { # having trouble here
        list(
            "Choice A"=1,
            "Choice B"=2
        )
    } else {
        list(
            "Choice C"=1,
            "Choice D"=2
        )
    }
    # inputs
    tagList(
        radioButtons(
            inputId=ns("firstInput"),
            label="Choose one:",
            choices=list(
                "Choice 1"=1,
                "Choice 2"=2),
            selected=1
            ),
        radioButtons(
            inputId=ns("secondInput"),
            label="Choose another",
            choices=input2Choices,
            selected=1
            )
        )
}

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Sidebar  
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sidebarSel_ui("test")
        ),
        # Main panel
        mainPanel(

        )
    )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm getting an "object 'input' not found" error. If I do actually have to split these inputs into different modules, send the results of the first to the server and then send that back to the second to make it work, I think I can figure that out. It seems odd to not be able to access inputs within the *same* UI.

Comment: You need to put the logic that defines the selected value for `input2` in the module server function, not the module UI.  In fact, ou haven't even defined a module in your code, let alone called it.  Also, I doubt the condition `ns(input$firstInput == 1)`, whilst syntactically correct, is what you want.  I suggest you work through the tutorial on modiues [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) before doing anything else.

Comment: @Limey, yeah, I started with that tutorial - it just wasn't obvious about how to use the module server to kick anything back to the inputs. I also got thrown off by the fact that I could base the `if` statement above on `id` without having to write a module server and call it in the main server at all and get it to work at that level. All set now - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to the hint from @Limey:

```
library(shiny)

# Sidebar selector UI module
sidebarSel_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    # inputs
    tagList(
        radioButtons(
            inputId=ns("firstInput"),
            label="Choose one:",
            choices=list(
                "Choice 1"=1,
                "Choice 2"=2),
            selected=1
            ),
        radioButtons(
            inputId=ns("secondInput"),
            label="Choose another",
            choices=list(
                "Choice A"=1,
                "Choice B"=2
            ),
            selected=1
            )
        )
}

# Sidebar selector server module
sidebarSel_server <- function(id){
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session){
            observeEvent(input$firstInput,{
                # conditional choices for input2 based on input1
                input2Choices <- if (input$firstInput == 1) { 
                    list(
                        "Choice A"=1,
                        "Choice B"=2
                    )
                } else {
                    list(
                        "Choice C"=1,
                        "Choice D"=2
                    )
                }
                updateRadioButtons(session, "secondInput", choices=input2Choices)
            })
        })
}

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Sidebar  
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sidebarSel_ui("test")
        ),

        # Main panel
        mainPanel(

        )
    )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    sidebarSel_server("test")
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Key changes:

- set up the second `radioButtons` input as usual with the first set of choices
- set up an `observeEvent` in the module server that handles the `if` logic and
  spits the choices list back with `updateRadioButtons`
- call the module server in the main server function

More roundabout than I was expecting, and it looks like one cannot, in fact, refer to the inputs of a module ui within the module ui itself. The trick is to do the work in the module server and kick it back to the ui.

Comment: You can’t refer to the module inputs within the module ui function. But you can refer to them within the module server function. The same is true of the main ui function and the main server function.  If I get the time I’ll rework you example tomorrow.

Comment: I misread your final para.  You've done it the way I would have done.  My apologies.